# Does iCloud needs to be enabled in Device to store data from app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios5, icloud

First of all thanks for the help! I am working on a application that we are planning to store some data in iCloud space. We have added iCloud code to app but unable to figure out few things as mentioned below:

1. Is it necessary to have iCloud enabled in user device (user might
   choose not to use iCloud via Settings -> iCloud) to save my app data
   to iCloud?
2. As far as i know data on iCloud is being saved on the
   basis of apple id of user; so if user changes his apple id via
   Settings -> Store then where my app data will be stored (app is
   downloaded via different apple id) ?
3. How to test iCloud on
   development environment. When i install the app (via testflight
   using adHoc mpp) on various devices it does not synchronize the
   data)?

Thanks again!
MP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer to my own question. Please refer below apple link:

Refer [link1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/TestingandDebuggingforiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH8-SW1) and last section of [link2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesignForCoreDataIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH3-SW1) from apple official website.